Bounding Boxes Variation in AWS Rekognition
In my AWS Rekongition project the bounding box obtained for a person nearer to the camera and the bounding box obtained from a person farther from camera seems strange. I process a video stream.
First:
 {"Top": 0.16380199790000916, "Left": 0.29940199851989746, "Width": 0.5602120161056519, "Height": 0.670058012008667}

Second:
 {"Top": 0.14867399632930756, "Left": 0.33712801337242126, "Width": 0.2856130003929138, "Height": 0.29319098591804504}

First is farther, and the second is nearer. But the height and width are strange. Why would it be?
I was trying to eliminate people who are farther away using bounding boxes, but now I can't do so as the data is not properly given width and height.
